# Source for Normalized File of ETF Holdings

Tags: market-data, etf

Does anyone know of a source for a data feed containing ETF Holdings for most ETF firms such as Ishares, Proshares, State Street?  I know Bloomberg has this info, but I'm looking for a vendor that can deliver this info without all of the constraints that BB puts on their data.

Comment: What constraints does Bloomberg add that you would like removed?

Comment: @chollida To be clear, I'm not talking about technical constraints, instead I'm talking about the administrative constraints of establishing a BB subscription and being compliant with BB's data policies.

Comment: We're trying to have all data sources question in the same thread and to avoid create new ones.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more with labeling this question as a "duplicate". The user is specifically looking for "ETF holding data," which specifically is not answered in the question you referenced @SRKX